# What's the logic flaw in this conditional?

Tags: php

I've created this code branch so that if the permalink settings do no match at least one of the OR conditions, I can execute the "do something" branch. However, I believe there is a flaw in the logic, since I've set permalinks to /%postname%.html and it still tries echo's true;

I believe I need to change the ORs to AND, right?

```
if (get_option('permalink_structure') !== "/%postname%/" || 
          get_option('my_permalinks') !== "/%postname%/" || 
    get_option('permalink_structure') !== "/%postname%.html" || 
          get_option('my_permalinks') !== "/%postname%.html"))
{
//do something
    echo "true";
}
```

Comment: Over 200 characters in one line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are testing :

```
if(get_option('permalink_structure') !== "/%postname%/"
```

And your permalink is `/%postname%.html` -- which means it is not `"/%postname%/"`

So, that first portion of the condition is `true`, and you are entering into the `if` block -- and the other ones are not even evaluated.

I suppose what you want is to use `&&`, and not `||` :

```
if(get_option('permalink_structure') !== "/%postname%/" 
    && get_option('my_permalinks') !=="/%postname%/" 
    && get_option('permalink_structure') !== "/%postname%.html"
    && get_option('my_permalinks') !=="/%postname%.html"))
{
//do something
    echo "true";
}
```

Which would mean :

- if permalink is not `"/%postname%/"`
- and permalink is not `"/%postname%/"`
- and permalink is not `"/%postname%.html"`
- and permalink is not `"/%postname%.html"`
- then, echo true

Answer (score 4):

when you do a construct like this:

```
 if($a != 1 || $a != 2)
```

then it will always be true since for this to be false $a should be 1 and 2 simultaneously.

your construct is similarly flawed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, switch them to `AND` and it should work.  You could instead reverse those to `==` and put a `!` in the front.

Answer (score 0):

Use ands, not ors. Have made the same mistake myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
if !(get_option('permalink_structure') == "/%postname%/" || 
           get_option('my_permalinks') == "/%postname%/" || 
     get_option('permalink_structure') == "/%postname%.html" || 
           get_option('my_permalinks') == "/%postname%.html"))
{
    echo "true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other say, use `AND` (`&&`) instead of `OR` (`||`). If you are unfamiliar with [Boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic), here in short:

```
TRUE and FALSE == FALSE
TRUE and TRUE == TRUE

FALSE or FALSE == FALSE
TRUE or FALSE == TRUE
```